# Microsoft Edge - long tap behaviour

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-10-mobile

On Microsoft Edge running on Windows 10 Mobile, if the user presses the screen for about one second, a box appears with the option "Select all" (Select all text on the page).

This is just fine, but this option also appears if the user long taps on an image - and this interferes with a script I use for mobile image zoom.

Any idea on how to disable this default behavior? If I add `ms-user-select: none;` in the CSS the "Select all" box still appears (even though the text on the page can no longer be selected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $("#my_image_id").bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
});
```

Ok, this does the trick - disables the context menu just for my particular image.